# Paint.NET Save to Imgur?

Tags: paint.net, imgur

Currently, I have to save the image to file, then fish it out of the file system.  Then using the [Imgur SendTo](http://imguruploader.codeplex.com/releases/view/40965) app to send it to Imgur.

It would be awesome if I could save to Imgur straight from Paint.NET.  Does something like that exist as a plugin or as a method?

Answer (score 4):

[Upload to  plugin](http://forums.getpaint.net/index.php?/topic/13242-upload-to-v26/) is not supported anymore.

I found [Imgur Uploader](http://forums.getpaint.net/index.php?/topic/26732-imgur-uploader/) which works well.  Download it and put it in the `C:\Program Files\Paint.NET\Effects` folder.

Answer (score 2):

There is the *[DragFrom](http://forums.getpaint.net/index.php?/topic/21031-dragfrom-v11/)* plugin that enables to upload your image to Imgur (and other sites that are compatible with the drag & drop gesture).

[image: DragFrom]

You still have to open [imgur.com](http://imgur.com) in your browser though...

Comment: Similar to this method would be to copy the whole image and paste it, since Imgur now accepts pasted images as well as drag and drop. Select all (`Ctrl` + `A`), copy (`Ctrl` + `C`), navigate to http://imgur.com, paste (`Ctrl` + `V`).